# vim: need to workaround a bug in undofile()

Tags: vim, undo

The persistent undo feature in vim uses an internal function `undofile()` to determine the filename of the undofile for the current buffer. There is a bug in vim 8.0 on one of my machines where `undofile()` does not correctly escape the path separator.

```
:echo undofile(@%)
/home/bhawkins/.vim/undo/%home%bhawkins%some%path%to%code.c
```

Those bare `%` characters don't work on this machine (not sure why not). The correct result of this command should be:

```
:echo undofile(@%)
/home/bhawkins/.vim/undo/\%home\%bhawkins\%some\%path\%to\%code.c
```

So it fails to load the undo history, even though it saves the history correctly. For example, when I manually load the undo file, persistent undo magically starts working (just for that one buffer):

```
:rundo /home/bhawkins/.vim/undo/\%home\%bhawkins\%some\%path\%to\%code.c
```

I tried setting this up as an `autocmd FileReadPost` in my `.vimrc` by putting the result of `undofile()` into a `let` variable--but I can't figure out how to escape the `%` characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be very tricky to reference a variable in an `autocmd`:

```
autocmd BufReadPost * :let undofilename=substitute(undofile(@%), "%", "\\\\%", "g")
autocmd BufReadPost * :silent execute "rundo ".g:undofilename
```

In my opinion this is yet another reason that vim should use a well-organized language like python for its command line and scripts, instead of torturing people with this campy homegrown mess known as "vimscript".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
1  redir => oldundo
2  echo undofile(@%)
3  redir end
4  let oldundo=oldundo[1:]
5  let newundo=substitute(oldundo,"%","\\\\%","g")
```

The first three lines capture the undo path in `oldundo` variable.
Line 4 removes the first character (`^@`) from `oldundo`. The last line replaces `%` with `\%` and stores the result in `newundo`. Finally to use the new path you can type:

```
:rundo <c-r>=newundo<cr>
```

Here `<c-r>` means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>. And `<cr>` represents the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: No, I asked for an `autocmd`, not a manually entered command. This answers some other question that I didn't ask.